# Issue with select tag on phonegap/cordova on windows phone device

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova, windows-phone

I'm developing an mobile hybrid app on phonegap/cordova and experience an issue that i cant resolve on windows phone.

So I'm creating an select tag as you can see

```
<select>
        <option>item 1</option>
        <option>item 2</option>
        <option>item 3</option> 
</select>
```

and I'm using some css from a framework called Chocolate-Chip UI

```
select {
background-color: transparent;
border: solid 2px #000000;
color: #000000;
height: 30px;
padding-left: 5px;}
```

giving me the result that I've expected. You can see the result bellow

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRaf9.jpg

The problem seems to appear when i select an item, since my background color its white (and i want it that way), my font color comes white also which results on a full white select. You can see the result below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYi2O.jpg

When i press out of the of the select tag it becomes all normal again.

So my question is, Can i manipulate the color of the font on item selected via css? I Know i can manipulate the background on select:checked or select:focus  color but the color of the font doesnt seem to work

Do you have any suggestions that might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've successfully solve my problem. It seems that IE11 has some expecific directives on focus event.

So the code i've done its like this

```
/*The event on select*/
select:focus::-ms-value{
background:#FFFFFF;
color:#666666;}
```

This should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that on mobile devices inputs remain in focus even after making your choice - this is given away by the blue border in the second image. To style the focused state use the following selector:

```
select:focus {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
```

This would be the official way to do what you are trying to accomplish. If this does not work then it could be a browser specific issue that will be harder to work around.